# Microsoft graph v1.0 download a document from documents library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am calling the following GET url to get some items from a sharepoint sites list

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items?expand=fields

How can you download files which are in a document library which are related to the sharepoint site?

I can collect the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl from the documents library and the file gets downloaded but I don't know how to relate the file to an item in a sites list.